# How to build a python egg for a TRAC plugin?

Tags: linux, python, subversion

I'd like to install a [mercurial plugin](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracMercurial) for Trac. The manual provides an svn path with the source code. I need to create an "egg" from that source code. Do I need to have SVN installed in order to do this, or can this be done in a different way?

<sub>(I'm very new to Linux, I've been using it only for the past two weeks.)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If you scroll down on the page you linked to, you'll see that they have it so you can download a zip file snapshot of each version.

The rest of the instructions are on that page as well, for how to build the egg.